How to type hint an abstractmethod property and make mypy happy?
Rewriting this question, because it turns out what I thought the problem was, wasn't the problem.  In fact, I have a seemingly equivalent case that mypy doesn't complain about.
Here is an example where there has no mypy complaints that seems equivalent:
class TableLoader(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def FieldToDataHeaderKey(self):
        # dict of model dicts of field names and header keys
        pass

    def set_headers(self, custom_headers=None):
        for mdl in self.FieldToDataHeaderKey.keys():

class StudyTableLoader(TableLoader):
    FieldToDataHeaderKey = {
        Study.__name__: {
            "code": CODE_KEY,
            "name": NAME_KEY,
            "description": DESC_KEY,
        },
    }

However, this seemingly equivalent code produces a mypy error:
class PeakAnnotationsLoader(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def add_columns_dict(self):
        pass

    @classmethod
    def add_df_columns(cls, df_dict: dict):
        for sheet, column_dict in cls.add_columns_dict.items():
            # ^^^ This is the line that produces the error
            ...

class IsocorrLoader(PeakAnnotationsLoader):
    add_columns_dict = {}

produces the following errors from mypy:
DataRepo/loaders/peak_annotations_loader.py:213: error: "Callable[[PeakAnnotationsLoader], Any]" has no attribute "items"  [attr-defined]
DataRepo/loaders/peak_annotations_loader.py:321: error: Need type annotation for "add_columns_dict" (hint: "add_columns_dict: Dict[<type>, <type>] = ...")  [var-annotated]

I can't figure out how to make mypy happy in the second case.  All of this code works, BTW.  How do I satisfy mypy here?
Is there a different way that I should be creating abstract class attributes?  I have multiple classes that inherit from TableLoader and none of them produce mypy errors WRT FieldToDataHeaderKey.  Is it just that mypy doesn't handle .items() the way it handled .keys()?

Does add_df_columns do anything if add_columns_dict is None? I don't think making an abstract property optional is the solution here.

You might be right, although making it None when the derived class happens to not need "to add columns" is straightforward.  Basically, the abstract class does everything, but the derived class only needs to describe how the conversion of the input data (a dict of DataFrames) into a universal format should be done.  It does that by defining attributes that describe how the conversion should be done.  The method that does the conversion is in the base class.

I suppose I could put everything in 1 data structure, so that it's always defined, but that would increase the complexity of already complex data structures.  RN, there are 4 data structures used in the conversion: add_columns_dict (this one), column_rename_dict, drop_columns_list, and merge_dict.

Or I guess I could make an empty dict infer that there are no columns to add.  That's probably the best solution, but it still feels like a work-around.  Seems like declaring the type of the return value as optional should work.

"The abstract class does everything". You should probably have multiple abstract classes, and the concrete class can inherit only from those it needs.

You should probably have multiple abstract classes. IMO, that kind of defeats the purpose of creating a base class.

The other problem is that cls.add_columns_dict, even if not None, is not a dict; it's a property object. You need to access the property from an instance of cls in order to get the dict returned by the method.

I'm discovering that.  I tried setting an empty dict in the derived class and I still get the same error, so I apparently didn't understand what was going on. So I guess I need to learn how to create an abstract class attribute.  I've done this in other classes, but not with a dict... mypy doesn't complain about the other one I have that is a list...

OK. Now I'm confused. Apparently, I have done this with a dict before and mypy didn't complain about it when I use .keys() off it in the code... So confused.

Going to edit my question to better define the problem based on what I just learned...

Re: your update, you "replaced" the abstract method with an actual dict, rather than a getter for the property that the ABC "requires".

@chepner - Forgive me, but I don't understand the point you're making. Yes, the derived class has a class attribute of the same name as the abstract method. @Codrin edified me that adding @property forces the derived class to have an instance attribute (that the class attribute surreptitiously satisfies - if I understand it correctly). I'd incorrectly believed that the property/abstractmethod forced the derived class to have a class attribute by that name. Regardless, forcing the class attribute to exist in the derived class was my intent, but nothing changed WRT that in my update.

In the PeakAnnotationsLoader class the add_columns_dict method is at the instance level while the add_df_columns method is at the class level. Using cls.add_columns_dict is like using PeakAnnotationsLoaderChildClass.add_columns_dict which in theory returns what mypy says it returns, a callable.
The code works because you override the add_columns_dict method and make it a static field so PeakAnnotationsLoaderChildClass.add_columns_dict returns the value of this field. The parent doesn't enforce in any way the child classes to override add_columns_dict as such and thus mypy throws this error.
The error goes away if you make the add_columns_dict method an instance-level method by removing the @classmethod annotation.
The intended way to override an abstract property would be the following:
class IsocorrLoader(PeakAnnotationsLoader):
  @property
  def add_columns_dict(self) -> Optional[Dict[str, Dict[str, function]]]:
    ...

This would break your code and it wouldn't work anymore since you are not making add_columns_dict a static field of the class anymore.
From my current knowledge, it's not possible to have an abstract class method that's also a property.
Making add_columns_dict an abstract class method instead of an abstract property could also make this error go away. Your code could then look like:
class PeakAnnotationsLoader(ABC):
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def get_add_columns_dict(self) -> Optional[Dict[str, Dict[str, function]]]:
        pass

    @classmethod
    def add_df_columns(cls, df_dict: dict):
        add_columns_dict = cls.get_add_columns_dict()
        if add_columns_dict is not None:
            for sheet, column_dict in add_columns_dict.items():
                ...

class IsocorrLoader(PeakAnnotationsLoader):
    @classmethod
    def get_add_columns_dict(self) -> Optional[Dict[str, Dict[str, function]]]:
        ...


Hmmm... My goal is for the derived class to only define datastructures that describe how a method in the base class should do a data conversion.  I ise @property  and @abstractmethod to essentially require the derived class to define these class attributes.  I have other code that does this and mypy dopesn't complain about it, so there's something going on here I don't understand, but your insights about class versus instance appear to possibly be a piece of the puzzle. I am editing the question now to add what I've learned.

OK... I think I'm slowly absorbing your answer.  Let me try some things.  I think you're onto something, though I still want this to be a required class attribute defined in the derived class via an abstract base class.

I just saw your edit, the difference between the 2 examples is that in the first example, you have an instance-level method (def set_headers(self, ...)) while in the 2nd example, you have a class-level method (def add_df_columns(cls, ...)). You can look at class methods like static methods, so in the second example, you are trying to access something that doesn't exist on a class level, a property that only exists after an instance is created. The code works because in the child class you take what is an instance method in the parent and make it a static method in the child.

I had been using @property (with @abstractmethod) for the better part of a year now and I never realized that (and correct me if I'm wrong) it was essentially forcing the instantiated derived class to have an instance attribute! Now this situation makes much more sense. I'm also realizing that there's no clean way to force it to define a class attribute?

That's exactly it! And unfortunately yes, since you can't use all 3 at the same time (@property, @abstractmethod, and @classmethod) you can't really force derived classes to have certain class attributes. You can force them to have class methods but not class attributes. Check this out if you are curious about a discussion about @classmethod and @property which was possible in Python 3.9 but got deprecated in 3.11 and will be removed in 3.13

I ended up solving this a bit differently (with working code that satisfies mypy by making the methods into instance methods), but your answer is what helped me understand what was going on.  I realized that I didn't really need the methods to be class methods.  I also newly understand the way that I'm doing it is somewhat of a trick. I'll probably play around with it some more before deployment. Thanks so much for your answer.
